# laravel 5 Changing database name in runtime

Tags: database, connection

is there a way to change the database name of a connection instead of adding another? 
It's okay if I add 3 or 5 databases in Config.database.connections, but what If I have 100 or more databases I am working with?
Since all use the same HOST, USERNAME and PASSWORD, is there anyway to just change the database name dynamically and work with that during the whole session?
I tried

```
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', 'database1');
```

but when I try using queries , it still uses the default one.

Answer (score 9):

If anyone still is searching for the answer for this question, answer is here:

You can change database name(not connection) at run time as follows:

Import following classes on top of your controller or middleware:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Then inside function, change database name as follows:

```
DB::disconnect('mysql');//here connection name, I used mysql for example
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $dbName);//new database name, you want to connect to.
```

After this whenever you will make query to extract any data from any table, it will search into new database provided.

Please note, this is for changing database name in **SAME** connection while runtime.

*I hope it helps*

Answer (score 1):

In my case using Laravel 6 disconnecting and setting alone did not work.
I still had to reconnect the database like so:

```
 \DB::disconnect('mysql'); 
 \Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $database_name);
 \DB::reconnect();
```

More about the case can be found here [Laravel 6 config()->get('database.connections.mysql') not matching DB:connection()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59580981/laravel-6-config-getdatabase-connections-mysql-not-matching-dbconnection)