# How to use laravel DB::setDatabaseName?

Tags: database, laravel

I use `DB::setDatabaseName(<database name>)` to reset the databasename, then I use `DB::table(<table name>)->get()` to retrieve data. However laravel does not change to new database.

This is my error message:

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42P01]:
>   Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "t" does not exist LINE 1: select
>   * from "t" ^ (SQL: select * from "t")'

The `table t` is in another database. I think when I use `DB::setDatabaseName(<database name>)` it would work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: where you define database connection configuration like username password ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41138711/8970463

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your database of detail information, but this help you to check database have changed.

```
// current database is 'db_1'
echo DB::getDatabaseName(); // return db_1

// Set database to 'db_2'
DB::setDatabaseName('db_2');

// If success, should return 'db_2' now.
echo DB::getDatabaseName();

// Check database tables.
DB::select('show tables');
```

Comment: I use the postgresql, when I use DB::select("SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables where tableowner = '<owner name>'") to check the result. The result that display previous tables. Is it the bug of framework?

Comment: What you mean is that calling `DB::getDatabaseName()` will see that the database has changed, and will it get the same results as the previous database when running SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue.
But changing the database solely might not always work.

You could use *config->set()* like so

```
config()->set('database.connections.mysql', $database_name);
```

But in my case I had to reconnect the database to change it dynamically.
So maybe this one works for the OP.

```
\DB::disconnect(); 
config()->set('database.pgsql.database', $database_name); // psgl = Postgress
\DB::reconnect();
```

You'll find more info here [Laravel 6 config()->get('database.connections.mysql') not matching DB:connection()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59580981/laravel-6-config-getdatabase-connections-mysql-not-matching-dbconnection)

*Hope it helps*